# Android: How to refresh screen after (brightness) setting changed

Tags: java, android, refresh, settings, screen

I'm trying to do is create a code so as the user moves the SeekBar it changes the phones brightness (as its being moved) and sets it to the phones **MAIN** settings.
I've snipped the part of code I believe is the issue..

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, progress);
}
```

#### If you need any more information please let me know. It does change the brightness but you have to refresh the screen - press the power button and unlock it again - for it to work and I can't think of a way to do this programmatically

*Any help or advice will be appreciated, thanks :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need WindowManager to help you change brightness. My english is not good, so I write an example code like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ScreenBrightnessSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBrightness);

    //Brightness is a float-point number between 0 and 1，But getProess() returns Int, so, we can setMax(100), and then we div 100 later.

    ScreenBrightnessSeekBar.setMax(100);  
    ScreenBrightnessSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {  

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}  

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}  

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            setScreenBrightness((float)seekBar.getProgress()/100);
        }  
    });
}

private void setScreenBrightness(float b){

    //get window attributes and save in layoutParams
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();  
    layoutParams.screenBrightness = b;

    //display the new brightness
    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
}
```

//new code:

```
    SeekBar screenBrightnessSeekBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    screenBrightnessSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBrightness);  
    screenBrightnessSeekBar.setMax(255);
    screenBrightnessSeekBar.setProgress((int) (android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
            getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 255)));

    screenBrightnessSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {  
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}  

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                        android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, progress);

                WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();  
                layoutParams.screenBrightness = (float)progress / 255;

                getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And you will need this permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: thanks for this but its not exactly what I'm wanting. I want to be able to change the brightness in the MAIN setting of the Operation System (Settings > Display > Brightness). This only changes the brightness in the activity. Any ideas?
Your english is fine by the way :)

Comment: Oh, now I get what you mean. Actually, if you put our codes together, you will get what you want. The new code has been written above. I tried that, it works ok.